# Book about a DNA hacker who could customize people using animal DNA

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I read this book approximately 10 to 15 years ago; here is what I remember. Might not be 100% but should be close.

It was about an expert hacker who learned to hack DNA code.

He was a twin but his sister died when they were younger.  She died when they were kidnapped as children.

The hacker had blue eyes and "blue" might have been in the title. The book had a female police officer trying to track him down.

Most of the book was about a genetic disease that transferred person to person swapping DNA from everyone.  The hacker made it customizable with animal DNA. He could give someone a custom-made version of the disease so they could have animal traits like fur or feathers or eagle eyes. He gave himself fangs under his fingernails for defense but for others it was mostly cosmetic or fun stuff.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good questions, it might help you remember additional details you can [edit] into your question.  You should be specific too; approximately what year, or how long ago was "years ago?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is "[The Changeling Plague](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0451459105)" (2003) by Syne Mitchell.

> After Mahn's disease ravages the population, viral engineering, which created it, is prohibited by the Beijing Treaty. Money still talks, though, and wealthy cystic fibrosis patient Geoffrey Allen obtains an untested viral treatment that seems to work perfectly. Then his associates fall ill and die of strange cancers and genetic diseases they shouldn't have developed.
>
> Allen is quarantined at the Centers for Disease Control, where Lilith Watkins is pointed in the direction of a cure by Idaho Blue, a hacker whose sister died of Mahn's. The medical establishment succeeds, it thinks, in controlling the new malady but fails to understand its malevolent potential. Idaho, however, comes to an unorthodox understanding of the disease, and the upshot of this is a change in the face of human nature.

Comment: Thanks! That is the book I was thinking of.